# React-Redux: What is a appropriate initial state for a fetching flag?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have implemented a fetching flag that indicates whether data is currently being fetched or not. The fetching flag works fine and jumps from `isFetching = false` to `isFetching = true` and vice verca as it should. But I have problems to find out what the initial state of the fetching flag should be? Both `isFetching = true` and `isFetching = false` leads to unwanted behavior.

**Option 1:**

In case the Fetching Flag  is true:

`const initialState = { isFetching: true };`

...and I try to render some data based on the fetching flag:

`{!isFetching === false? <LoadedComponent props ={data} /> : <LoadingSpinner />`

everything works fine. However after clearing the redux state
e.g., after a user logout the Fetching falg jumps to true again.
Keeping the application in the loading state.

```
isFetching: true
isFetching: true
isFetching: false
isFetching: true // <- after clearing store, jumps into loading state and remains there. e.g. causing for a not logged in user a loading state
```

**Option 2**:

In case the Fetching Flag  is false:

`const initialState = { isFetching: false };`

...and I try to render some data based on the Fetching Flag...

`{!isFetching === false? <LoadedComponent props ={data} /> : <LoadingSpinner />`

... the component trys to render the data even though it is not ready, thus causing an error.

```
isFetching: false // <- trys to render but data not ready.
isFetching: true
isFetching: false
isFetching: false
```

Both options are not really appropriate in my case. So how should I set my initial fetching flag to avoid this behavior? I'm happy for any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why we recommend [treating loading state like a "state machine"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#treat-reducers-as-state-machines), preferably with [an enum for the loading state value](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#loading-state-for-requests):

```
interface ItemsState {
  items: Item[];
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
}
```

That way you can distinguish between "we haven't tried fetching it yet" vs "we tried and succeeded/failed".

See [the Redux Essentials tutorial page on "Async Logic and Data Fetching"](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) for examples of this in action.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to encapsulate three or more things in a boolean variable. Fetching means fetching and nothing else. You can't deduce anything else from this state.

```
const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  error: null,
  data: null
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.FETCH_PENDING: {
      return { ...state, fetching: true, error: null };
    }
    case Actions.FETCH_SUCCESS: {
      return { ...state, fetching: false, data: action.data, error: null };
    }
    case Actions.FETCH_REJECTED: {
      return { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.error, data: null };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

As markerikson wrote, there're usually 4 states that you must somehow render: idle, pending, succeeded, failed. Idle usually only occurs when the component mounts. Here is [a sample App](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-template-forked-81jqk?file=/src/App.js) that requests jokes from an endpoint:

```
function App({ joke, fetching, error, fetchJoke }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => fetchJoke()} disabled={fetching}>
        add a thing
      </button>

      {fetching ? (
        <span>Loading...</span>
      ) : joke ? (
        <p>Joke: {joke}</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <strong>{error}</strong>
      ) : (
        <span>Idle: Click to load a joke</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```